# OptaPlanner solver: multiple best solutions

Tags: optaplanner, vehicle-routing

I am solving a planning problem with OptaPlanner. After configuring solver I call solve() method and wait for it to produce the solution. The question is, what if I want to compare few Best Solutions created by solver method with each other and choose one of them. Is it possible?
  I want to set termination condition by comparing last two solutions with each other and seeing how they differ from each other. That is why I want to implement this.
   Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy answer: add a `SolverEventListener` to the `Solver` and listen to `bestSolutionChanged()` events to remember them. That suffices for most users.

The difficult answer: See "pareto optimization" in optaplanner docs. That isn't supported out of the box *yet*, but several users added it themselves by hacking the `BestSolutionRecaller`.